# Angular default page routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS(1) is used in my UI.
I need change behavior for default page.
If user is not authorized he should navigate to login page other case -> special page.

Configuring anonymous module

```
anonimModule.config(function ($routeProvider, anonimTemplateManager, anonimUrlManager) {
  $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: anonimTemplateManager.getLoginPath(),
          controller: 'loginCtrl'
      })
```

I can set only one time this behavior (only for login for example) but *the special* page is not accessible if user authorized.
I tried to get access to *$rootScope* from *when* (to solve my issue) - unsuccessfully.

Is it possible to implement dynamic behavior for routing?
Could I have example or idea to implement it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use state routing and then you may use statechangestart event for example:-

```
.state('user.dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/my/dashboard/deshboard.html',
        controller: 'myDashboardController'
        url: '/dashboard',
         access: {
            loginRequired: true
        }
```

and then in app.js you may use $stateChangeStart and some auth service that will check if user is authrize to access that state or not

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
            function (event, toState) {
                var authorised;
                if (toState.access !== undefined) {
                    authorised = authorizationServie.authorize(toState.name);
                   if (authorised ===  false) {
                        $state.go("loginState");
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use otherwise.

Just chain it, like so:

```
.when('/foo', {
   templateUrl: 'foo.html',
   controller: fooController
)
.when('/bar', {
   templateUrl: 'bar.html',
   controller: barController
)
.otherwise(
    redirect: '/foo'
)
```

Comment: Bas, how does it check if user is authorized?

Comment: You could try to write a service, where you check for the authorization if the user is authorised set a boolean (or some other var where you can see that the user is authorised) and check it in the controller

Answer (score 2):

You can also write `$state.go('/url')` to move to another page in your `anonimTemplateManager.getLoginPath()` method.

few other methods for same work

- `$location.url();`
- `$state.go('/url')`
- `$window.location.href = '/index.html';`

not tried everything.

Answer (score 1):

you save authorization data in local Storage when you login in application، you should check any time state change if user do not login in your application,your application must route in login page or display alert...
for doing this:

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",["LocalStorageModule"]);
app.run(function($rootScope,$state,localStorageService){
     rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState, parameters, from) {
     if(localStorageService.get("authorizationData") !== 'logined')
        $state.go("loginPage");
    });
}
```

even you can save previous state with from variable in stateChangeSuccess event parametr and save this in rooScope for coming back to current state.